# How do 3D player collision work?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, collision-resolution

I don't really know how to explain this but I have always wondered how simple player movement collision work. Take Half-Life or Counter-Strike for example.

Their player collision against the world are very simple - AABB collision box vs. simple brushes. For example, you walk towards a wall and when you collide with it, you are perfectly still.

While in Unity, there we have PhysX which is not even the slightest suitable to achieve perfect, almost pixelated(in 3D) player collisions.

Comment: Seems like you're asking a few different questions here. Perhaps you can narrow the scope a bit and tell us the problem you're facing.